# Expect-like functionality to IO.gets?

Tags: shell, elixir, elixir-mix

For example, if I wanted to automate authorizing a hex user. Something like

```
mix hex.user auth
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

expect "Username: "
send -- "$HEX_USERNAME\r"
expect "Password: "
send -- "$HEX_PASSWORD\r"
```

mix hex.user auth asks for Username: and Password: but I don't think expect works for this

Comment: Do you want Expect like functionality in Elixir? I'm confused by your statement that expect doesn't work for this. Stdin is Stdin regardless of programming language.

Answer (score 4):

Given the following script:

```
u = IO.gets("Username: ") |> String.strip
p = IO.gets("Password: ") |> String.strip

IO.puts ""
IO.puts "#{u} - #{p}"
```

You can pass input like this:

```
$ export HEX_USERNAME="hexuser"
$ export HEX_PASSWORD="hexpass"
$ echo "$HEX_USERNAME\n$HEX_PASSWORD" | elixir test.exs
Username: Password:
hexuser - hexpass
```

So, you could use

```
echo "$HEX_USERNAME\n$HEX_PASSWORD" | mix hex.user auth
```